# Why throwing exception which is a reference calls copy constructor?

Tags: c++, exception, copy-constructor, throw

Why throwing exception which is a reference calls copy constructor?

```
struct Error
{
    Error() {}
    Error(const Error&) = delete;
};

int main()
{
    Error& error = *new Error;

    throw error;
}
```

Compilation error:

```
error: declared here
     Error(const Error&) = delete;
```

It does not happen when throwing pointer like:

```
int main()
{
    Error* error = new Error;

    throw error;
}
```

This is OK.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/throw

Comment: Peeps are very downvote-happy these days. Okay, so this information could have been found elsewhere - but that's the case with literally every question. This one is well presented and concise, and the misunderstanding is understandable (lol). Let's not be so downvote-happy.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: `throw Error{}` is a different example, though, if we maintain the premise that it is possible to "throw a reference" (which it isn't, which is the answer). So, no, it's not "distracting" - it is the very core of the question.

Comment: `Error error = *new Error` the only time I see code like this is when someone is coming from java, having always written `new`. As others are suggesting `throw Error{}` is enough, but if you wanted to create the variable beforehand, use `Error error{};` That is, instead of `Type var = *new Type(arg1, arg2);` you want to be writing `Type var{arg1, arg2};`

Answer (score 6):

You cannot throw a reference. [Throwing *always* copies the thrown expression value into a special area of storage set aside for thrown objects](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/throw). Otherwise, you'd almost always be "catching" a dangling reference, as is [theoretically] the case in your code.

Your `Error` type cannot be copied, so the program is impossible.

However, a pointer can of course be copied, and the main problem in your final example is a memory leak. Also your program will simply terminate at the `throw` statement as you don't have any `try`/`catch`.

Comment: Why dangling? I create the exception with 'new' and never delete it, so it should always exist. Why throw pointer should be different from throwing reference? Copy constructors should be only called when throwing by value, not ref or pointer.

Comment: @AndreyRubliov: Perhaps I wasn't clear. The dangling reference would be created in the hypothetical _first_ example which does not compile. The second example instead has a memory leak. _"Copy constructors should be only called when throwing by value, not ref or pointer."_ That is simply not true, as I have stated: you _always_ "throw by value", period.

Answer (score 0):

Before unwinding stack a throw operator (except throw; without an argument, used for rethrowing) creates an exception object (in a special memory area). Depending on circumstances, the object is initialized in different ways: constructor, copy constructor, move constructor (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) using what was provided to the throw operator. Providing the reference is ok, but three:

- if you provide a reference in an arguments list, it depends on receiving party, what is actually received, a reference or a value copy;
- compiler needs to initialize an exception object, because what was provide to the throw operator will not live when the exception handling catch block is running (the stack will have been unwound then; in case of the pointer, the pointer provided, though the object it points to in your case is alive, and in the catch block you have a copy of the pointer to the same object);
- it is not possible to initialize a reference in runtime;
  so, in your case, the compiler expects the copy constructor in order to initialize an exception object using the reference you provided (copy constructors usually takes values to initialize the object using references to the initial one).

When you pass a reference to Error to the throw operator, the type of the exception object is Error, and we need to initialize an Error exception object in that specific memory area..

When you pass a pointer to Error to a throw operator, the type of the exception object is a pointer to Error (Error *), so the pointer is copied, not the Error object which the pointer points to. The copying pointer to error has nothing to do with calling the copy constructor of Error, so you don’t have the error in that case.